# JavaScript: Toggling Between 2 Images Not Working, Using setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

New to JS. I am trying to toggle between showing two images, `dragon.svg`, and `dragon1.svg`, every 1 second starting on page load, and running indefinitely. However, my image only changes once, and then keeps running every second but not following the rules of my if/else statement.

My suspicion is that the function is not changing the value of a global variable called `dragonDiv` each time it runs, so each time it runs, it is using the original value of the `dragonDiv` variable.

On the HTML, I have a div with the image inside, like this:

```
<body onload="changeDragon();">
    <div id="dragonarea">
      <img src="images/dragon.svg"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

And then I have this JS, which should change the image to `dragon1.svg` if it is currently `dragon.svg`, and vice versa, every 1 second.

```
function changeDragon() {
  changeInterval = setInterval(dragonColorChange, 1000);
}

let dragonDiv = document.getElementById('dragonarea');
console.log(dragonDiv.innerHTML); // Correctly logs <img src="images/dragon.svg"/>

function dragonColorChange() {
  if (dragonDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="images/dragon.svg">') {
    dragonDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="images/dragon1.svg">';
    console.log(dragonDiv.innerHTML) // Correctly logs <img src="images/dragon1.svg"/>
  } else {
    dragonDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="images/dragon.svg">';
    console.log(dragonDiv.innerHTML) // Never makes it to this point
  }
}
```

As noted above, the console log tells me that it is correctly changing the image the first time, but after that, it seems like it is again taking the original value of `dragonDiv` (with the `dragon.svg` image) and running the function on that innerHTML again (so changing it to `dragon1.svg` again), rather than updating the innerHTML after running the function once as I'm telling it to do and forcing it to the else statement.

I tried putting the `dragonDiv` variable inside the `dragonColorChange` function as well as outside as a global variable. I tried using `document.getElementById('dragonarea').src` instead of replacing the entire innerHTML of the div tag. I tried using `===` instead of just `=`. I tried various other things for about 4 hours and I can't figure out how to get it to keep looping through the if/else statements.

Any mistakes I'm making in my code?

Comment: Why don't you change the src directly? elem.src = "imglink";

Comment: `<div>` does not have an `onLoad` event.

Comment: Ah fair enough, I tried adding onload to the body as well, with the same result. I will update my question to show the onload on the body tag so that others don’t repeat your comment.

Comment: I did try changing the elem.src directly, but ran into problems since src pulls the entire image URL, including the local path info. I could try that again but would need to do an additional step where I only take the last part of the URL.

Comment: Why not simply use CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the typo (= is assignment, == or == is comparison) you have several improvements you can make

1. Use addEventListener
2. Change src, not innerHTML, waste of DOM rendering
3. I suggest a data-attribute

```js
let changeInterval;
let dragonImage;
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  dragonImage = document.getElementById("dragonImage");
  changeInterval = setInterval(dragonColorChange, 1000);
})

function dragonColorChange() {
  const toggle = dragonImage.dataset.toggle
  const src = toggle === "0" ? "images/dragon1.svg" : "images/dragon.svg";
  dragonImage.src = src;
  dragonImage.dataset.toggle = toggle === "0" ? "1" : "0";
}
```

```html
<div id="dragonarea">
  <img id="dragonImage" data-toggle="0" src="images/dragon.svg" />
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like it will work! I will try it out when I come back to my computer. However, will I run into any issues because src comes back as the full URL source, including the local host info?

Comment: My script does not care about the URL, hence the data-attribute

Comment: Oh awesome! Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I already commented this morning but I don't see my comment anymore, so thanks @mplungjan! This was the only solution that successfully mitigated for the src issue I kept running into, where it was trying to compare full local host source paths with relative short paths. Thank you SO MUCH! I took your code and modified a little to allow for toggle between more than 2 images, and that worked as well.

Comment: But if you had shown that example from the beginning, then I could have written a generic one that will toggle between original source and source+"1" OR using an array of objects, between on_src and off_src

Answer (score 2):

Typo I guess, use === or == for comparison.
Also, onload function on body had different quotes [”] (when I copied and pasted on jsfiddle, it didn't work) instead of ["]

```js
function changeDragon() {
  changeInterval = setInterval(dragonColorChange, 1000);
}

let dragonDiv = document.getElementById('dragonarea');
/* console.log(dragonDiv.innerHTML); // Correctly logs <img src="images/dragon.svg"/> */

function dragonColorChange() {
  if (dragonDiv.innerHTML === '<img src="images/dragon.svg">') {
    dragonDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="images/dragon1.svg">';
    console.log(dragonDiv.innerHTML) // Correctly logs <img src="images/dragon1.svg"/>
  } else {
    dragonDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="images/dragon.svg">';
    console.log(dragonDiv.innerHTML) // Never makes it to this point
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="changeDragon();">
  <div id="dragonarea">
    <img src="images/dragon.svg" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey @lakshya sorry about the different quotes in body, I made that update from my phone so it defaulted to special character quotes. I updated to normal quotes. However, even with 3 === I am still getting their error, in fact it isn’t running at all!

Comment: It seems to be working for me (you can run the code snippet here and see the logs). Also, here's a jsfiddle for the same https://jsfiddle.net/2f0mzv7t/ (I changed image urls so that you can clearly see the image changing every second)

Answer (score 2):

Here I compare and change the image.src directly, instead of the div's innerHTML, as others have suggested already.

HTML:

```
<body onload="changeDragon();">
    <div id="dragonarea">
      <img id="dragon-image" src="images/dragon.svg"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
function changeDragon() {
  changeInterval = setInterval(dragonColorChange, 1000);
}

let dragonImage = document.getElementById('dragon-image');

function dragonColorChange() {
  if (dragonImage.src === 'images/dragon.svg') {
    dragonImage.src = 'images/dragon1.svg';
  } else {
    dragonImage.src = 'images/dragon.svg';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick, this looks like what I will need. However, whenever I tried console logging the src, I got the full source URL including local host info, which seemed to be messing things up. I’ll try your code when I get back to my computer though.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you need the ===.

Here's one way to do it and keep the variable scoped to the function. I'm using .getAttribute("src") instead of just .src since it gets the relative url path.

Note that dragonColorChange isn't being passed into setInterval. It's the function returned by calling dragonColorChange.

```
  const changeDragon = function () {
    changeInterval = setInterval(dragonColorChange(), 1000);
  };

  function dragonColorChange() {
    let dragonImg = document.querySelector('#dragonarea img');
    return function () {
      dragonImg.src = dragonImg.getAttribute("src") === "images/dragon.svg" ? "images/dragon1.svg" : "images/dragon.svg";
    }
  }
```

Comment: I suggest you use get AND setAttribute if you use getAttribute for consistency's sake, but at least the getAttribute will fix the localHost issue

Answer (score 0):

In the if condition there is a typo. Instead of comparison with `==` or `===` there is assignment operator which will assign rather than compare. Try changing that to comparison.

Comment: I tried === because I agree that it should be === instead of =, but for some reason it prevented the function from running entirely (didn’t even change the image once). I think you’re right that that is part of the problem but I think there must be another problem too that I’m missing.

Comment: Instead of comparing innerHTML, the src can be compared by assigning the image an id and then accessing src as `document.getElementById("myImg").src === "images/dragon.svg";` would be better. This is beacause right now innerHTML is being compared. And as you mentioned the console output is `<img src="images/dragon1.svg"/>`.
There is an additional forwardslash '/' before the the tag ends. What is being compared in if statement is '<img src="images/dragon.svg">'. Notice there is no forward slash in this. Try adding a forwardslash and that should work. However I would suggest comparing src.

Comment: Ah good point @abhinum95, I didn’t notice the forward slash!